# pyqt4: less round-about way of removing item from QListWidget?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to remove an item whose name I know. I came up with:

```
item = lw.findItems(name, QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly)[0]
lw.takeItem(lw.indexFromItem(item).row())
```

Is there any more direct way of doing this? Something closer to `lw.removeItem(name)`?

Answer (score 1):

This leaves a bit of ambiguity for multiple entries with the same text.  I would lean more toward something like

```
[ lw.takeItem( i ) for i in range( lw.count ) if lw.item( i ).text() == name ]
```

This will remove all items matching name from the list.  If you only want to remove the first instance, you need to expand this into a full for-loop that breaks at the first match.

Good luck!