# Python -QListWidget.TypeError: range() integer end argument expected

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am working with python plugins.I have one QListWidget as **fieldsList**_2 on my form.I am listing some item to it, as query result.My code is as follows:

```
c = self.db.con.cursor()
self.db._exec_sql(c, "SELECT desc,survey from bio")
            for row in c.fetchall():
                    acoustic=unicode(row[0])
                    if (acoustic[0:3]=="ACO" ):

                            surv=unicode(row[1])
                            self.fieldsList_2.addItem(unicode(row[1]))

                            for i in range(self.fieldsList_2.count):
                                    if self.fieldsList_2.item( i ).text() == surv:
                                            self.fieldsList_2.takeItem( i )
```

I wanted to prevent QListWidget **fieldsList**_2 from listing duplicate entries.But when i try to run the above code ,it gives error:

```
  for i in range(self.fieldsList_2.count):
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got builtin_function_or_method.
```

I tried **range(1,self.fieldsList_2.count)**..but no success.If 3 same items exist,then i wanted to keep one of them into **Qlistwidget**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the error message given, try changing from

```
for i in range(self.fieldsList_2.count):
```

to

```
for i in range(self.fieldsList_2.count()-1):
```

count()-1 because the element you just added was added to the end of the list, and if you wish to keep one you should ignore the last.

An alternative is to only add an item if no duplicate exists, here is some pseudo code:

```
duplicates = self.fieldlist_2.findItems(surv, QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly)
if duplicates.size() == 0:
    self.fieldsList_2.addItem(unicode(row[1]))
//skip the loop part since it's not necessary using this alternative
```

Comment: @Kristofer--yes..but the both the same items are removed..i wanted to keep one of them...

Comment: @poonam: Added parts to deal with that problem in the answer.

Comment: @Kristofer-ok but syntax error at Qt::MatchExactly...and count()-1 does not add even single item to list...

Comment: QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly is the PyQt4 way to write it, and the whole "remove duplicates" loop is not necessary if you go with my second alternative since no duplicates are inserted, thats the whole point.

Comment: @Kristofer-yes..i know..but it says:TypeError: 'sip.methoddescriptor' object is not callable

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074198/pyqt4-less-round-about-way-of-removing-item-from-qlistwidget) shows using findItems.
[This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238473/python-form-not-displayed-using-show-method) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014826/python-typeerror-init-takes-exactly-4-arguments-1-given) shows that you have had the same error previously, try remembering how you solved it(if you did) or search for a [common reason](https://groups.google.com/group/thg-dev/browse_thread/thread/e2338c084b973bd8)?